# Turn off "double-tap to unlock" on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: samsung, lock-screens

For some reason, whenever someone calls me, the Samsung Galaxy S7 now shows the phone put, tells me to double-tap to unlock, then it does it a few seconds later. I have never seen this before, never wanted to double-tap.

I have gone to the talkback and it is off.

I don't know why it started doing this but how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Display -> Double tap -> Turn on 
double tap is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Also try this.
Go setting / accessibility / talkback. Turn off talkback. When talkback is on, it will prompt to double tap to unlock. But this double tap is using two finger and swipe up.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Galaxy S7 SM-G930U and had the same issue. Both during incoming and outgoing phone calls my phone would display a padlock symbol and a message reading "Double tap to unlock." This would overlay the call information screen behind. When the message was displayed, I was unable to hear a ring or voice on the call.

The workaround was to quickly double-tap and press speaker to allow the phone call to function.

I had recently installed a new head phone jack inside the phone and had also received a software update. Trying new phone apps did not solve the problem, so I suspected it was a hardware issue. I went through all of the steps necessary to remove the back cover, disassemble the phone and removed and reattached the battery connection. I had taken this step to replace the headphone jack. Somehow the battery connection must have been loose because reattaching the battery solved the 'double-tap' issue for me. Disassembling your phone is a process, be careful, or take your phone to a shop to check it.

Answer (score 0):

0

I have a Galaxy S7 SM-G930T and had just changed the battery. When looking for an answer to the double tap to unlock problem, one answer suggested proximity sensor problem and then found Androi_toulouse answer. Both these suggested to me that the problem might be with the ear speaker not being connected properly since that was what was not working even when I double tapped. Removing the back cover which I had only seal light at the sides, I inspected the area at the top end of the fone and found that the small top circuit board was not seated correctly. A couple of tabs at the top needed to be tucked under the frame. Remove the board and loosened 3 screws on the speaker/batt cover to lift and help accomodate the board so that it laid flat and secure. Turned the fone back on and made a call ... everything worked fine after that.